# Ativar e desativar ação com click em JS

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extensão, whatsapp

estou enfrentando um problema.
Irei colocar o código e explico o que não estou conseguindo fazer.

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  const header = document.querySelector('._1QUKR');
  
  if(header) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "2.5x";
    button.classList.add("twoTimesButton");
    header.appendChild(button)
    
    //const teste = document.querySelector(".twoTimesButton");
    
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const audios = document.querySelectorAll("audio")
      
      audios.forEach(audio => {
        console.log(audios)
        audio.playbackRate = 2.5
      });
    })
    header.appendChild(button);
  }
}, 1000)
```

Essa função faz a aceleração dos áudios do WhatsApp.
Como eu poderia fazer com que ativasse e desativasse? Ou seja, clicar no botão e acelerar e depois clicar e voltar a velocidade normal. Já tentei usar alguma condicional, mas não tive sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode armazenar os valores em variáveis.
Suponhamos que o estado inicial é false, no primeiro clique ele muda o estado para true e atualiza a varivável de rate com 2.5 mas pode ser dinâmico um valor que o usuário escolher.
e no próximo clique ele atualiza o valor de isActive para false e seta o valor original no rate.

vou deixar um exemplo de como poder ser feito.

```
<button id="speed">Aumentar</button>

window.onload = function() {
  let isActive = false;
  let playSpeedRate = 1;
  const button = document.getElementById('speed');

  button.addEventListener('click, function() {
    if (isActive) {
      isActive = false;
      playSpeedRate = 1;
    } else {
      isActive = true;
      playSpeedRate = 2.5;
    }
      console.log(isActive);
      console.log(playSpeedRate);
  });
}
```

Comment: Sensacional! Era isso que precisa, pensei em fazer algo parecido, mas não consegui estruturar. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Magina, tudo de bom cara.
se você puder avaliar o thread votando positivo pode ajudar mais pessoas com esse mesmo problema.